# Keyboard support

Tags: keyboard

I have a Yamaha P115 keyboard. When using the double X brace my keyboard wants to slide off as there is no stops built into the brace. How can I stop the movement before the keyboard hits the ground?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the top tubes of the brace (the ones you place your keyboard on) are level.
2. If the brace is level and the keyboard still slides around, you need some high-friction padding (e.g. rubber or foam) between the tube and keyboard.

Rubber stops are fairly common on these stands:

[image]

But they're easily lost: they aren't locked in place so they'll slide off when you apply too much force.

Comment: First thing I do with any stand (mic/k'bd etc) is pop rivet the rubber/plastic endstops in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use velcro tape - hook and eyes - glued on the top bars of the stand, and the matching places under the keyboard. And if the stand is to be taken out of the house, pop rivet or use adhesive on the endstops. Otherwise they *will* eventually escape.

I guess you mean the keyboard slides towards or away fom you. that's what the endstops are there for. If you mean it slides sideways, then a couple of strips of wood, or carpet, or rubber glued under the keyboard will stop that.

I have used foam for lagging water pipes split and slipped over the top tubes, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also fix the upper arms of the X by aparallel or diagonal line, cable or wire like clothe horse to prevent the worst case scenario:
[image]

Comment: That will stop the stand collapsing, but not stop anything on top sliding.

Answer (score 0):

What about rubber bands? You could wrap some of the thick ones around the tubing on the keyboard stand to create a lot of friction. They're also free or relatively cheap.

Another option is friction tape which can be found at hardware stores.